# What's the difference between tkinter's Tk and Toplevel classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In Python 3, I run the following from the interactive shell:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> type(tkinter.Tk())
<class 'tkinter.Tk'>
>>> type(tkinter.Toplevel())
<class 'tkinter.Toplevel'>
```

Both of these create individual windows. I assume that `tkinter.Tk()` returns the "main" window of the tkinter app, while any additional windows should be created with `tkinter.Toplevel()`.

I noted that if you close `tkinter.Tk()`'s window, both windows close. Also, if you call `tkinter.Toplevel()` without a call to `tkinter.Tk()`, two windows are created (one of them being the "main" window that, when closed, will also close the Toplevel window).

Is this accurate? Are there any other differences that I should be concerned with?

Comment: At a base level: `Tk` is the whole app and `Toplevel` is just a window.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your summary is accurate. One of tkinter's core architectural features is that the widgets exist in a hierarchy with exactly one root window. That root window is what you get when you instantiate `Tk`.

Instantiating `Tk` does more than create a window, it initializes the entire tkinter framework. It actually starts up a hidden tcl interpreter which does the actual work of managing widgets. Tkinter is just a python wrapper around this interpreter.

If you attempt to create some other widget without explicitly creating a root window first, one will be created automatically since every tkinter application must have exactly one root window.

Comment: One can add that you can actually use that hidden Tcl interpreter via the `tkinter.Tcl()` method without creating any windows, but that would be a rare sight in Python land. (it is a silly way to sidestep the python GIL as the Tcl interpreter has no GIL and might support threading).