# Tk(), Toplevel() and winfo_toplevel(). Difference between them and how and when to use effectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, toplevel

I am trying to understand how a widget is being created. And I found above three functions are getting used in creating a widget, yet I couldn't come up with the difference and the advantage of one over the other. Even though, I had taken a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655219/whats-the-difference-between-tkinters-tk-and-toplevel-classes) that still leaves me with confusion (and it hadn't said anything about `winfo_toplevel` too).

Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Root widget")
root.mainloop()

window = Toplevel()
window.title("Window widget")
window.mainloop()
```

On running above code "Root" widget is getting created. On closing "Root", two widgets are created with one titled "Window widget" and other being unwanted. On closing unwanted widget, "Window widget" is also getting destroyed. 
What is actually happening here and how to overcome?

Another sample:

```
class ldo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.appOutline()

    def appOutline(self):
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        self.menuBar = Menu(top)
        top["menu"] = self.menuBar
        self.subMenu1 = Menu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuBar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.subMenu1)

app = ldo()
app.master.title("Sample UI")
app.mainloop()
```

On the other hand, this code is using `winfo_toplevel()` where the widget looks perfectly fine. Here, my assumption is, `Frame` plays a role of creating widget and `winfo_toplevel()` is an enhancing tool to other tkinter items. But would like to know what it does actually.

However, below snippet is not working:

```
winf = winfo_Toplevel()
winf.title("Winfo Widget")
winf.mainloop()
```

And returning such error:

```
winf = winfo_Toplevel()
NameError: name 'winfo_Toplevel' is not defined
```

What is the exact difference between Tk(), Toplevel() and winfo_Toplevel(). What and when should one be used effectively. Looking for really a better understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between tkinter's Tk and Toplevel classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655219/whats-the-difference-between-tkinters-tk-and-toplevel-classes)

Comment: I have looked upon the same and detailed my query. Please consider and give me a better explanation if you are familiar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *On running above code "Root" widget is getting created. On closing "Root", two widgets are created with one titled "Window widget" and
>   other being unwanted. On closing unwanted widget, "Window widget" is
>   also getting destroyed. What is actually happening here and how to
>   overcome?*

When you create any widget with the absence of an actual `Tk()` instance, a `Tk()` instance automatically gets created, thus resulting in an unwanted Toplevel-like widget when the second part of the first code snippet runs. Additionally, when a widget gets created with the absence of `master` option, it is assumed that the instance is a child of one of the `Tk` instances, in above case, there's only one, and that's the one that got automatically created. When a parent gets destroyed all widgets that are under it also gets destroyed, so when you close the unwanted widget that is an instance of `Tk`, the `Toplevel` instance also gets destroyed as its parent is destroyed.

On the second part, [`winfo_toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_toplevel-method) refers to the automatically created `Tk` instance again and creates other children with that automatically created `Tk` as the parent, which should be technically fine but would be harder to maintain as a code, than the standard ways of creating the same GUI I'd presume.

---

> ```
> winf = winfo_Toplevel()
> winf.title("Winfo Widget")
> winf.mainloop()
> ```

In the code piece above, unless imported or otherwise defined `winfo_Toplevel` has no meaning, first of all, it's not as same as `winfo_toplevel` as python is case sensitive. Secondly, even if [python](/questions/tagged/python) wasn't case sensitive, it would still throw an error as it is a method and it lacks the first positional argument, which is the object instance to the class of which the `winfo_toplevel` method is also defined for.

Essentially, you're trying to use a case-insensitive spelling of a method, as if it is a class name such as `Toplevel` or `Tk`, which `winfo_toplevel` has almost nothing to do with.

---

Examine the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("This is the actual Tk instance, root")

toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
toplevel.title("This is a Toplevel, whose parent is root"),

r_lbl = tk.Label(text="""This label is a children to the default master, 
    as it lacks the first positional argument for an explicit parent 
    assignment.""")

r_lbl2 = tk.Label(r_lbl.winfo_toplevel(), text="""This label checks who the
    toplevel parent for r_lbl is, and then selects that parent as a parent
    to itself.""")

r_lbl3 = tk.Label(root, text="""This label will appear on root, as it's
    explicitly passed as the first positional argument, which is the parent,
    as root.""")

t_lbl = tk.Label(toplevel, text="""This label will appear on toplevel, as it's
    explicitly passed as the first positional argument, which is the parent,
    as toplevel.""")

t_lbl2 = tk.Label(t_lbl.winfo_toplevel(), text="""This label checks who the
    toplevel parent for t_lbl is, and then selects that parent as a parent
    to itself.""")

r_lbl.pack()
r_lbl2.pack()
r_lbl3.pack()
t_lbl.pack()
t_lbl2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

In conclusion, `Tk`, while being a `Toplevel` widget, is also *the* tcl interpreter for the entire GUI that runs in a thread. There can be more than one present, [which is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045401/7032856) as usually multiple instances of it is unjustified, but there also *has* to be at least one instance present in order to have a GUI.

`Toplevel` can be considered to be the only visual part of a `Tk` instance, and it can be used when there is a need for multiple window-like widgets.

Finally, `winfo_toplevel` is merely a method returns the reference for the `Toplevel`-like parent that a widget is in, be the parent an instance of a `Toplevel` or a `Tk`.

Comment: But if you say **winfo_toplevel** also refers to the automatically created, why not the below snippet is working. 

winf = winfo_Toplevel()
winf.title("Winfo Widget")
winf.mainloop()

Comment: @suganthi Because there is no need to be an instance of a `Tk`, as there's no widget created yet at the time `winf = winfo_Toplevel()` is run. Even if there was, that's not how the method works anyway, it needs an object of the created widget to be attached as the object to the method as in `self.winfo_toplevel()` in the last code in the Original Post.