# Tkinter Popup Window While Process Runs

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, I have a window that I would like to create when a process is initialized to run another Python script, which would then close when the script completes. Below is what I have so far:

```
window = tk.Toplevel()
window.geometry("400x90")
window.wm_title("Process is Running")
process = subprocess.Popen("python3 run_a_script.py", shell=True)
process.wait()
window.destroy()
```

The script is running, but the popup window never appears. It does appear after the script completes if I remove `window.destroy()`, but it does not automatically close.

Is there a way to have the window be created before run_a_script.py is run, and then have it automatically close when the script completes?

Comment: Is window.destroy() the last line in the script? As if so it meets your requirements; the window is closed at the end of the script.

Comment: This code is actually a function triggered by pushing a button, but yes, that's the end of the function. However, the button indents (as though it's been pressed) and remains indented while run_a_script.py runs. When run_a_script.py completes, no popup window appears. So, I believe it is creating and then destroying the window after the script is run.

Comment: Can you please provide run_a_script.py - it might be just running the script and then it runs it is so fast that it already closes just moments after it is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All tkinter updates are handled by the tkinter `mainloop` and during the execution of the external script, tkinter `mainloop` does not take the control until after `window.destroy()`, so you cannot see the window because it has been destroyed when tkinter takes back the control.

To show the window during the execution of the external script, you can:

- call `window.update_idletasks()` before calling `subprocess.Popen(...)` to let tkinter to show the window.  However you cannot interact with the GUI during the execution of the external script.

```py
window = tk.Toplevel()
window.geometry("400x90")
window.wm_title("Process is Running")
window.update_idletasks() # show the window
process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "run_a_script.py"])
process.wait()
window.destroy()
```

- use `.after()` to check periodically whether the process has completed or not.

```py
window = tk.Toplevel()
window.geometry("400x90")
window.wm_title("Process is Running")
process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "run_a_script.py"])

def check_process():
    if process.poll() is None:
        # process is still running, check again 100ms later
        window.after(100, check_process)
    else:
        # prcoess is completed, destroy the window
        window.destroy()
check_process() # start the checking
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting this right, then you never tell the window to "appear".
Try adding:

```
window.update_idletasks()
window.update()
```

or

```
window.mainloop()
```

to show the window

Edit: Also, I typically use **tk.Tk()** for the main window instead of **tk.Toplevel()** for clarity.
[What's the difference between tkinter's Tk and Toplevel classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655219/whats-the-difference-between-tkinters-tk-and-toplevel-classes)

Comment: Ah, I should've included the main window, using tk.Tk(). This is a popup that appears after a button is pressed in the main window.